# What is SetClassLongPtr(GCL_CBCLSEXTRA) used for?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, setclasslong

In the documentation of [`SetClassLongPtr`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633589.aspx), it says that setting `GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` "does not change the number of extra bytes already allocated".

What, then, is `SetClassLongPtr(..., GCL_CBCLSEXTRA, ...)` used for?

Comment: Presumably, the value exists for its use in conjunction with the `GetClassLong[Ptr]` function, where it retrieves the size of the extra memory associated with the class.

Comment: @CodyGray: Er... what is it *used* for?

Comment: Uh you can store whatever you want in there. You request extra space when you register the class. See the `cbClsExtra` member of the `WNDCLASS` structure. No one really does this anymore, though, I don't think.

Comment: @Mehrdad: [`GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` is not a valid flag for `SetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx), so your question written as-is actually appears strange to me. Are you just asking for what the extra window bytes are for?

Comment: Yeah, I suspect that `SetWindowLongPtr` is actually a typo, and you meant `SetClassLongPtr`. They are two very different things, though both can have extra storage bytes.

Comment: @Insilico: Indeed, it was a typo, sorry... fixed

Comment: @CodyGray: I just realized, it seems like you're completely misunderstanding my question. I'm **not** asking what the extra class space is used for; I already *know* what it's used for. What I'm asking is what the **function call** `SetClassLongPtr(..., GCL_CBCLSEXTRA, ...)` is used for, because the documentation for `GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` says it doesn't change the reserved size.

Comment: Yeah, that was the point of my first comment. That the value exists for the `Get` function, not for the `Set` function. You asked what it's used for, and so I explained what it's used for in the `Get` function. I didn't post this as an answer because I actually have no idea what the *history* is, if it *used* to do something else for the `Set` function. Lots of things have changed over the years with the API docs, and MSDN doesn't maintain historical archives, just the most recent versions. If I can pull up an old Win 95-era copy of MSDN, I find a lot of very interesting things.

Answer (score 0):

As Cody Gray said in his/her comments as responses to OP's question and comments, `GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` should be used only in calls to `GetClassLongPtr` function.

There is no reason at all and probably it is also wrong to use `GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` in any call to `SetClassLongPtr` function.

Assume that there is a `struct` whose first field/member `p` stores an address of a buffer as pointer of type `void*` and second field/member `size` as an integer of type `size_t` that is the size of the buffer pointed by `p` in bytes.

Calling `SetClassLongPtr` with `GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` is as wrong as modifying the `size` field/member of the `struct` without modifying the field/member `p` of the `struct` and without reallocating, with `realloc` function for instance, the buffer pointed by the field/member `p` of the `struct`.

In C, you access the `size` field/member of the `struct` only for getting it's value, unless or until the buffer pointed by the `p` field/member of the `struct` has been reallocated, by call to `realloc` function for example, and only then you modify the `size` field/member of the `struct` for update.

Because of the fact that calling `SetClassLongPtr` with `GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` is wrong, the function `SetClassLongPtr` may always fail if `nIndex` is set to `GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` to prevent a crash of the application that may happen if the function `SetClassLongPtr` while `nIndex=GCL_CBCLSEXTRA` succeeds and does the modification.

Answer (score -1):

GCL_CBCLSEXTRA is **a valid flag** for GetClassLongPtr since Windows 2000 Pro.

It retrieves information about a size of Windows class’ memory used for storing extra information. Other words: it is a size in bytes of memory allocated after window-class structure used to register window class.

Comment: This is not what the question is asking.